# How can get ip Address form socket io in Golang

Tags: sockets, go, socket.io, golang-migrate

I use this code but cant get ip address . How can i get user ip/port address ?
I can get socket id with Id(). Below code work well but i cant find how can use more option and function for so variable.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io"

)
func main() {
    server, err := socketio.NewServer(nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println("server", server)
    server.On("connection", func(so socketio.Socket) {
        log.Println("so------->>  " ,so  )
        log.Println("id------->>  " , so.Id() )
        log.Println("on connection")

        so.On("chat message", func(msg string) {
            log.Println("emit:", so.Emit("chat message", msg))
            so.BroadcastTo("chat", "chat message", msg)
        })

        so.On("disconnection", func() {
            log.Println("on disconnect")
        })
    })

    server.On("error", func(so socketio.Socket, err error) {
        log.Println("error:", err)
    })

    http.Handle("/socket.io/", server)
    log.Println("Serving at localhost:5555...")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":5555", nil))
}
```

Comment: @cerise-limón below link is true link and work well
https://github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/tree/v1.0

Comment: @cerise-limón   your answer is right .Thanks a lot my brother

Comment: @cerise-limón  i like your answer and question to increase your reputation.i'am from iran and Thank you a lot .

Comment: This didnt work ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27234861/correct-way-of-getting-clients-ip-addresses-from-http-request

Comment: how can install  github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/tree/v1.0 in my golang? this code: go get github.com/googollee/go-socket.io dosnot work for me

Comment: You can use go.mod in your repo and then just do `go get -u blah` to update all to the newer versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this expression to get the remote address: `so.Request().RemoteAddr`

Comment: Thanks Cerise  