# How can I determine the actual IP Address or network interface of the incoming request, when Go http server listen on 0.0.0.0?

Tags: linux, go, networking

I have a host with multiple network interfaces and corresponding IP addresses, e.g., `net1: 1.1.1.1`, `net2: 2.2.2.2`, `net3: 3.3.3.3`. How can I determine the actual network interface when http request incoming, and the Go http server is listening on `0.0.0.0`

Comment: How can I access the LocalAddr() in the HTTP handler?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27234861/correct-way-of-getting-clients-ip-addresses-from-http-request) answer.

Answer (score 1):

The local connection info is rarely needed from within an http handler, so there isn't a direct interface to obtain the information. If you need the local address, it's added to the request context by the server under `LocalAddrContextKey`.

```
localAddr := req.Context().Value(http.LocalAddrContextKey).(net.Addr)
```

The alternatives would be to have separate listeners for each interface, or [hijack](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Hijacker) the `ResponseWriter` to get the underlying `net.Conn`.