# How do you get the RemoteAddr (remote IP address) when deployed on Google App Engine Standard in Go

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I want to obtain the *client/browser IP* address to rate limit unauthenticated clients in my Google App Engine Standard/Go web app.

In the deployed app `r.RemoteAddr` returns the empty string.

Enumerating through the request headers (`r.Header [string][]string`) provides only the following entries.

```
    Content-Length
    X-Appengine-Citylatlong
    X-Appengine-Region
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests
    Accept-Language
    X-Cloud-Trace-Context
    X-Appengine-Country
    X-Appengine-City
    Host
    Cache-Control
    Origin
    Content-Type
    Referer
    User-Agent
    Accept
```

No IP addresses.

How do you obtain the client IP?

Comment: What does the `RemoteAddr` field have? Is it just a proxy or load balancer, or is it correlated with the client?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222021/google-app-engine-golang-how-to-get-users-ip-address

Comment: RemoteAddr (when in App Engine) returns an empty string. Typically it has the IP address of the client, however, sometimes it gets the IP of the load balancer. To work around this, load balancers sometimes add an X-Forwarded-For header with the client's IP. The IP address of the client is obtained using system calls from the server the receives that receives the HTTP request. It's not passed from the client.

Comment: I assume this problem is specific to App Engine.

Comment: Also note this question does  a good job of enumerating all the possible headers used to pass client IP's, none of which are set by App Engine. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558869/getting-ip-address-of-client

Answer (score 0):

In Google App Engine `r.RemoteAddr` does in fact return the IP address (my bad). However despite [other recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222021/google-app-engine-golang-how-to-get-users-ip-address) 
`ip, _, err := net.SplitHostPort(r.RemoteAddr)` actual returns the error:

`address 2601:645:8101:7784:7112:5258:8ba3:c888: too many colons in address`

and no IP address.

Do not use `net.SplitHostPort` and you'll get an IPv6 address.

I've logged [an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71730783) with Google.

Comment: Note: that's a valid IPv6 address, you *might* want to take such addresses into acount as well for your purpose.